# Monte Carlo estimation of a constant?

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, monte-carlo

I am currently learning monte carlo and I dont quite understand it. In the question I am given, I am asked to estimate $\pi$.

So I am to write a Matlab code that computes a numerical estimate of $\pi$ using N points with $D = [−1, 1]^{2}$ and r = 1. Plot the absolute error of your estimate as a function of N on a log-log scale using the loglog command, for N = 1, 10, 100, 1000.

So my question is this, in matlab to define the domain would I use `rand(100,1)` to generate the points ? My second question is I dont quite understand what I am supposed to integrate here. My prof says:

We know that the area of a circle C with radius r is $A_{C} = \pi(r^{2})$
. Now consider a domain $D$ of area $A_{D}$ that contains C (i.e., $C ⊂ D$). If we sample points in
$D$ uniformly at random, then the fraction of points falling inside the circle, $N_{C}/N_{D}$, should
approach the ratio $A_{C}/A_{D}$ as the number of points, N, grows large. Since we know $A_{D}$ and
can measure $N_{C}/N_{D}$, we can estimate $A_{C}$ and thus we can estimate $\pi$ = $A_{C}/r^{2}$

So what does $A_{D}$ mean here ? Should I define it according to the area formula and the idea is that we don't know $C$?. I would appreciate if one could provide some help. Thank you

Edit:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Suppose that we didn't know the value of $\pi$ .  If we know that the probability of being inside the circle is $\dfrac{\pi}{2^2}$ in a square 2x2, then the number of points inside divided by the total number of points should provide the same ratio as $\dfrac{\pi}{2^2}$.  You can therefore divide out the $\dfrac{1}{2^2}$ and be left with just $\pi$.  Needless to say, the more points you test, the more accurate the ratio becomes.  Why wouldn't you know C?

Comment: For every sample $(x,y)\in [0,1]^2$, you should include antithetical $(1-y,1-x)$ (reflection across $x+y=1$ - similar for other quadrants) to reduce the variance.

Comment: @Neil Sorry, I dont quite understand why the probability of being inside the circle is $\pi/2^2$. Shouldn't it be $1/(\pi*2^2)$ for each point?

Comment: @PutsandCalls It is $\dfrac{\pi}{2^2}$ because in a 2x2 square, the area is 4.  The area of a circle of radius 1 inside said square is $\pi$.  Do you see now?

Comment: Yes thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pick points randomly in D. Then work out if the point lies inside or outside the circle (using distance formula). Repeat and keep track of what fraction are inside the circle. You can then multiple this fraction by the area of D (equal to 4) to get an estimate of $\pi$.

$A_D$ is the area of D. In your example the $2\times2$ square so area of 4.

Comment: Thank you for the help, and sorry for bothering you again. But would you mind helping me take a look to see if I am getting the correct idea in implementing the procedure using the distance formula ? (I posted the code above in the edit section because I thought it was a bit difficult to read). I implemented the condition in the `if statement` so if the distance of $x^2 + y^2 < 1$, then I would increment the number of times it lands inside the circle. At the end, I multiplied the number of times divided by the total number of times.

Comment: I haven't done Matlab in years (I'm assuming your syntax is correct) but it looks good . When you run it do you get values approximately close to $\pi$? How does your log-log graph look? It should have a negative slope.

Comment: Thank you Ian, the first case shows a negative slope as I increase N. Iterating 100 times for each value of N = 10,100,1000,10000 and taking the average (which is shown in the 2nd picture), it follows that I get a positive slope sometimes. Is this accurate ? I find it puzzling that the second picture actually rises since it should be more evident of a negative slope because I increase the number of simulations right ?

Comment: Given such a small sample size (N=10) there is the chance to get larger errors. Personally if I was giving this question to students I would do $10^3$, $10^4$, $10^5$, ... Repeatedly doing this and getting the average  of the error would give a closer linear slope.